# SQL query using COUNT with the Select statement

Tags: sql, count

Let's say, for example, that we’re looking for the number of orders each salesperson has taken for our first 10 customers. We can use both the `SalesPersonID` and `CustomerID` columns in our `GROUP BY`

I'm not 100% sure on how the `COUNT(*)` is returning the values on the 3rd column. I'm using AdventureWorks2008. What and how is the query returning the value of 3 - which is supposed to be the number of orders taken.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, SalesPersonID, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE 
    CustomerID <= 11010
GROUP BY 
    CustomerID, SalesPersonID
ORDER BY 
    CustomerID, SalesPersonID;
```

Result ==>

```
CustomerID SalesPersonID
----------- ------------- -----------
11000          NULL            3
11001          NULL            3
11002          NULL            3
11003          NULL            3
11004          NULL            3
11005          NULL            3
```

Comment: It's counting the number of records in each group. I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's counting the number of records for each unique CustomerId/SalesPersonId group.
It does seem like SalesPersonId is null for all entries in your sample, but it's still valid to group on it, and there are multiple groups because of the various customerIds